# Succubox - how to generate security faster

Tags: succubox

How do I generate security faster in Succubox?

I currently do not have a security department in my employees and no matter how many security robots I build rate at which it is generated is fixed.

Comment: At what stage are you in? How many employees do you have? Or what upgrades are available to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After buying the shop item `Skirt regulations again`, an event takes place which will unlock a new type of 'currency', animosity. After a while you can buy the shop item `Security department`. When you purchased this you'll be able to assign security forces. This will boost your security a lot when you assign employees to it, so that you'll be able to buy the shop items which require security. After this you'll be able to expand your 'workforce' when aquiring new workspace (e.g. continents).

Make sure keep a positive balance, because when you are securing more workplace (e.g. at war) it will cost money to maintain the security. If you have no balance you will not be able to conquer other workplaces. At the same time assign a lot to security. It will take a while (it took me an hour or two) but eventually you will have conquered all of earth. Apply the same principle later in the game.